# Deference between sim800 and sim900

Tags: atmel, sim900, sim800

I have developed a card with `sim900` and `ATmel`, and it works very well, but when I changed `sim900` for `sim800` it did not recognize the sim card.

Difference in hardware design?
SIM800,SIM800C modem operates from 3.4V to 4.4V supply range (Reduced operating range  !)
SIM900, SIM900A modules operate from 3.2V to 4.8V supply range.
SIM800 is having a Pin to connect with Bluetooth Antenna
Apart from these differences the hardware design is almost similar. The same hardware circuit can be used for the SIM IC if the generated supply is within 3.4V to 4.4V for both types..

Comment: You will get an error code if things are not set up. Can you tell the error code?

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue before. I tried to contact SIMCOM but I didn't get any response.

My solution was to give to the modem a few seconds more time to boot, before I sent any commands to it.

Even if you get an `ERROR` as a response when you check for the SIM card you can insist on polling the same command until a predefined timeout time.

Also, note that not all of SIM800 have a Bluetooth feature.

Answer (score 0):

Which country are you currently located? SIM900A works with Dual-Band 900/ 1800 MHz. I believe it was designed for US band while SIM800C is Quad-band 850/900/1800/1900MHz and may operate world wide.

Find out the bands used by your mobile service provider and use module compatible with the band.